# Despite iptables, I can access port 80 on Google Cloud - why?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, iptables

I am running google cloud container instance (cos-beta-70-11021-29-0) and I run nginx:

`docker run --name xx -d -p 80:80 nginx`

I can access nginx welcome page despite port 80 not being open in iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Why is so?

Comment: Access welcome page by localhost:80?

Comment: No, access http://external_ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to expose a port, you have to communicate the internal docker network with the external one, so Docker adds it's own `DOCKER` chain to iptables, managed by itself. When you expose a port on a container, using the `-p 80:80` option, Docker adds a rule to that chain.

On your rules list you can find:

`-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

If you don't want Docker to fiddle with iptables, you can add the argument `--iptables=false` to your Docker daemon executor, but then probably the 'expose' part of your docker command might not work automatically, and you might need to add some additional iptables rules. I haven't tested that.

You might find that options `/etc/default/docker` or `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` depending if you're using systemd, upstart, or others...

You might want to check either of this links:

https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file